# Unit test on angular directive with a service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to do unit testing on a directive that calls a service to retrieve posts and am confused on how to test the directive. Usually directive testing is easy with just compiling the directive element but this directive element is calling posts via a get call. How do I test this?

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  describe('Post directive', function() {
    var element, scope, postService, $rootScope, $compile, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(module('madkoffeeFrontend'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_postService_, _$rootScope_, _$compile_, _$httpBackend_) {
      postService = _postService_;
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      $compile = _$compile_;
      // $httpBackend.whenGET('http://madkoffee.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=3').passThrough();
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      spyOn(postService, 'getPosts');
      element = $compile('<posts post-num="3"></posts>')(scope);
      scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should get the posts successfully', function () {
      expect(postService.getPosts).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    // it('should expect post to be present', function () {
    //   expect(element.html()).not.toEqual(null);
    // });

  });
})();
```

This is the controller:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('madkoffeeFrontend')
    .directive('posts', postsDirective);

  /** @ngInject */
  function postsDirective() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        postNum: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'app/components/posts/posts.html',
      controller: PostController,
      controllerAs: 'articles',
      bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;

    /** @ngInject */
    function PostController($log, postService) {
      var vm = this;

      postService.getPosts(vm.postNum).then(function(data) {
        $log.debug(data);
        vm.posts = data;
      }).catch(function (err) {
        $log.debug(err);
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call getPosts() from your test: that doesn't make sense.

Tell the spied service what to return. The fact that it uses http to get posts is irrelevant for the directive. You're unit-testing the directive, not the service. So you can just assume the service returns what it's supposed to return: a promise of posts.

Tell the spied postService what to return:

```
spyOn(postService, 'getPosts').and.returnValue(
    $q.when(['some fake post', 'some other fake post']));
```

Comment: in the .when([]) scope, do I enter the post ids that i want to retrieve?

Comment: You enter what the service is supposed to return, and what allows testing your directive. If the service is supposed to return a promise of array of IDs, then enter an array of IDs. If it's supposed to return a promise of array of Post objects, then enter an array of Post objects.